# Angular nested http requests

Tags: angularjs, angular-services, angular-controller

Guys i woulde like to nest http requests to flickr api, my goal is get (using flickr.photos.search) ids of photos (parametrized via 'text'), then make a second call on flick.photos.getSizes and retrieve direct link to source image.

Here is my code, but any other ideas would be nice from you. The problem is that PhotoSearchService return then all $http calls are made. Any better ideas ?

Service:

```
angular.module('flickrGalleryApp').factory('PhotoSearchService', function ($resource) {
  const apiKey = '&api_key=my api key';
  const apiUrl = 'https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=';
  const method = 'flickr.photos.search';
  const format = '&format=json';
  const callback = '&nojsoncallback=1';

  return $resource(null,null, {
    search : {url:apiUrl+method+apiKey+format+callback,method: 'GET', isArray: false}
  });
});
```

Controller:

```
$scope.items = PhotoSearchService.search({text:'girl'}, function(response){
    var array = response.photos.photo;

    const apiKey = '&api_key=my api key';
    const apiUrl = 'https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=';
    const method = 'flickr.photos.getSizes';
    const format = '&format=json';
    const callback = '&nojsoncallback=1';
    var result = [];
    for(var i = 0 ; array.length; i++){
        var id = array[i].id;
      var url = apiUrl+method+apiKey+format+callback + '&photo.id=' + id;
      console.log(url);
      $http.get(url).then(function(resp){

        var array2 = resp.data.sizes.size;

        for(var j = 0; j < array2.length ;j++){
          if(array2[j].label.indexOf('Square') > 0){
            result.push(array2[j].source);
          }
        }
        return result;
      }, function(err){

      })
    }
  },function(error){

  });
```

html:

```
<ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in items">
      <span>{{item.source}}</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you make an $http.get call for each photo id returned by the first call, you have to await for all the calls to complete then return the result.
The trick to do this is to create a defer object and resolve it when the result array is full.

Take a look at [$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) to see how you can pull this off. Just keep in mind that you will return a promise which means you have to implement a success or error callback to get the resulting array